# Jquery Validate method not found laravel

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

Im building a laravel project and i wanted to validate my form with jquery validation because I use bootstrap modal for my form so i think this was the easier way, than to refactor the views.
But it doesnt not find the Validate method

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>Parduotuvė</title>

{{--jquery--}}
<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Datatables -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/myscripts.js"></script>
```

[image: The error]
Feels like i dont include the validate script, not sure why...

P.S. i also tried it with different jquery version 3.1.1 or 1.11.1 as it is mentioned in https://jqueryvalidation.org/ that it is tested with those versions.

Edit. My script code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#create_order').formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        err: {
            container: '#errors'
        },
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            full_name: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Šis laukas yra būtinas'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 6,
                        max: 40,
                        message: 'Įveskite savo pilną vardą'
                    },
                }
            },
            email: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Šis laukas būtinas'
                    },
                    emailAddress: {
                        message: 'Blogai įvestas el. paštas'
                    }
                }
            },
            number: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Šis laukas būtinas'
                    },

                }
            },
        }
    })
    .on('err.form.fv', function(e) {
        // Show the message modal
        $('#messageModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: try `$('form').validate()` instead `formvalidate()`

Comment: Include `jquery-validate.min.js` below `myscript.js`

Comment: maybe you have syntax error.. can we see the script code?

Comment: @ZaheerAttar. jquery-validate.min.js should be loaded before our validate function.

Comment: Hi, While those picture are showing your code. It will be better if it was a Text! You won't show a picture of your code you printed to a friend asking to debug? I'am pretty sure you can copy past faster than you print screen, edit, upload.

Comment: I edited the post with code. I tried using .validate() function, but with same results

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing 2 JQuery validation plugins.

You have included the JS reference to Jörn's library, https://jqueryvalidation.org/, the most popular and well known plugin (check the source, it includes the URL and developer's name):

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

But your Javascript code is using syntax used by a different validation plugin entirely http://formvalidation.io/, which I have not heard of.  `formValidation`, `framework`, etc are not used in Jörn's library, but do seem to be used in it, [according to the docs](http://formvalidation.io/getting-started/#calling-plugin).

Comment: yeah you are right, I just realised it, dumb mistake

Answer (score 0):

The Browser saves files such as .css, .js in the cache to improve reloading time. So when you have already opened your site once, updated your JavaScript file, your browser hasn't downloaded your function yet.

Check in the dev-tool-tab under sources, wheter your files have been updated.

If not, you have a few possibilities:

- Open with another browser
- Open in Incognito Window
- Delete cache manually

Comment: They are uploaded

Answer (score 0):

### Check Example below form validation using jQuery validate Plugin

```js
$( "form" ).validate({
    messages: {
        name: "Name is required.",
        email: {
            required: "Email is required.",
            email: "You must provide a valid email address."
        }
    },
    focusInvalid: false,
    submitHandler: function() {
        alert( "Successful submission" );         
    }
});
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
body {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
body input, body button {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

form > div {
    margin: 1em;
}
form button {
    width: 100%;
}
label { display: block; }
input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0.2em;
}
button {
    padding: 0.2em;
}

input.error {
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
label.error {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<form>
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Include : -**  `<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>`

Comment: Tried using this method with id selector like this:     $('#create_order').validate({ . Also i included same scripts as in example, still getting the same error.

Comment: You have to take main form id if you want to implement validation on particular form

Comment: What do you mean main form id? It is my only form if i got that right. if i use ('form') selector, this validation would happen on every form? Anyway i did try that selector but the function error is still the same. :/